# How do I implement type safety in my client interface?

Tags: java, api, caching, type-safety

I have a caching api that uses an array as storage for the cache. How do I assure type safety in my interface? I'm not too familiar with the notion in java so I appreciate if you can include a detailed answer.

Client API

public class ClientCacheServiceImpl extends InternalCacheServiceImpl {

```
public ClientCacheServiceImpl(int sets, int entries, String algorithm) {
    super(sets, entries, algorithm);
}
```

Internal API

public class InternalCacheServiceImpl implements InternalCacheService {

```
private final int numberOfSets;
private final int numberOfLines;

public final CacheElement[] cacheArray;
public final String algorithm;

public InternalCacheServiceImpl(int numberOfSets, int numberOfLines, String algorithm) {

}

public final Object get(Object key) {
```

}

public interface InternalCacheService {

```
public Object get(final Object key);

public void  put(final Object key, final Object value);

public int size();

public void clear();
```

}

public class CacheElement {

```
public int tag;
public Object data;
public boolean isEmpty;
public long timestamp;
```

}

Comment: Unclear what specifically you're after, but you should probably start with generics.

Comment: Even using generics it doesnt mean it's type safe? The idea is to make sure all the key value pair are of one type

Comment: Of one type, or of the same type?

Comment: Please be more precise on what you want to make more type safe. Do you want to get rid of type Object for key and value?

Comment: of the same type.

Comment: The entries in the cache are supposed to be typesafe.

Comment: Im not very clear myself what that means that's why Im posting it on here for more senior developers to shed some light on this the way I understand is, it requires to have a way to check all the instances that are being inserted into the cache are of the same type through out the executions of the program but thats my interpertation of type safety is that even correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should introduce the generic parameter type T as follows:

```
public interface InternalCacheService<T> {

      public T get(final T key);

      public void  put(final T key, final T value);

      public int size();

      public void clear();
    }
```

You implement class for Integer typed keys and values would look like this:

```
 public class InternalCacheServiceImpl implements InternalCacheService<Integer> {

    private final int numberOfSets;
    private final int numberOfLines;

    public final CacheElement[] cacheArray;
    public final String algorithm;

    public InternalCacheServiceImpl(int numberOfSets, int numberOfLines, String algorithm) {

    }

    public final Integer get(Object key) {
       //find the cached element by key and return it. Lets say it is the ith element
       return (Integer) cacheArray[i].data;
    }
}
```

Comment: but why is this type safe? How do we know we don't have instances of various objects being put in the cache? Where is that check being made?

Comment: Because the type T is fixed when you implement this interface in a concrete class. For example when you do this: public class InternalCacheServiceImpl implements InternalCacheService<Integer>. In this case you fix the type T to be Integer for class InternalCacheServiceImpl. The compiler will then be able to check that the key and value are of type Integer.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: I've extended the answer above with the example of type Integer. In this case the client who is using your cache via the interface is only able to put objects of type Integer into your cache although the data structure CacheElement theoretically could store any Object type.